# How to make a canvas fluid

Tags: javascript, canvas, responsive

I have a canvas which gets its full-width size from the wrapper of the page. The canvas includes an image.

The wrapper is responsive but the canvas doesn't resize with the wrapper.

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
// set the canvas element's width/height to cover #wrapper
var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');
var wrapperStyle=window.getComputedStyle(wrapper,null);
canvas.width=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
canvas.height=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));
//
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var img=new Image();
    img.src= "els.png";
    ctx.drawImage(img, (canvas.width-img.width)/2, (canvas.height-img.height)/2, 990,172);
    // set "erase" compositing once at start of app for better performance
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

var canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
}

$("#canvasTop").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin:auto; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
}

#container {
 position:absolute;
 width:80%;
 height:80%;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin-left:60px;
 }

#canvasTop {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
   Stuff happen here ...
   </div>
 </div>
 <canvas id="canvasTop" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: Maybe `window.addEventListener('resize', function () {})`

Answer (score 1):

#### Detecting resizes

You have to subscribe to the `window`'s resize event:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", updateCanvas);

function updateCanvas() {

  // update canvas size (and position) here
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  // redraw canvas content based on new size
  // ...
}

updateCanvas();   // initial call
```

As a resize of the canvas will make it clear its content, we have to redraw all content again.

#### Using CSS (not recommended)

You do not want to resize using CSS in most cases as this will stretch everything drawn to the canvas making it blurry. However, in the cases where you still do use CSS you can set the size of canvas based on CSS size this way:

```
#canvas {
  width: 100vw;   /* or use 100% depending on your scenario */
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

Then in the `resize` event handler:

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();  // get absolute size in pixels
canvas.width = rect.width;
canvas.height = rect.height;
```

This should give you a 1:1 relationship between bitmap size and element size. If you're use padding or border you would have to add sizes of those as well. Those are best avoided with canvas. Instead wrap the canvas in a div element and set such styles on that instead.

#### Dealing with event stream

Another thing to be aware of when doing resizing is that there will be many events sent to the subscriber. Most of which you won't need. So to make it more fluid and responsive you can debounce the events:

```
var timer;
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(updateCanvas, 100);  // adjust time to liking
});
```

Comment: @K3N Do I add this at the bottom of my code after var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
init(container, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, '#000000');'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
#canvas{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```

VW stands for viewport width, and VH stands for viewport height so that literally means the whole viewport (the viewport is the visible side of the window).

Comment: I've already tried this but noticed that it stretches the canvas on resize and distort to draw. Thanks anyway..